# concatenate strings using sass

Tags: css, sass, grid

I would like to write a sass loop like so.

```
fractions: '';
@for $i from 1 through 4 {
    $fractions : $fractions + 1fr + '';
    .grid-#{$i} {
        grid-template-columns: fractions;
        display: block;
    }
}
```

I would like the output to be something like,

```
.grid-1 {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr; 
}
.grid-4 {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr; 
}
```

not

```
.grid-1 {
    grid-template-columns: " 1fr"; 
}
.grid-4 {
    grid-template-columns: " 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr"; 
}
```

I'm looking for a sass utility/function that I can use to remove the quote around the strings.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
$fractions:'';
@for $i from 1 through 4 {
    $fractions : $fractions + 1fr + ' ';
    .grid-#{$i} {
        grid-template-columns: #{$fractions};
        display: block;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I also came across another implementation: ```unquote($fractions)``` works as well.

Comment: Values like `border: 1px solid #{$primary + 'AA'}` also works.