# Concatenate list items into a property value with quoted spaces

Tags: sass

Given a string `$prefix=Note` and a list `$attributes = a b c` what SCSS loop will produce this? —

```
 ::before {content: "Note " attr(a) " " attr(b) " " attr(c)}
```

This earlier post ([concatenate strings using sass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51244750/concatenate-strings-using-sass/51245499)) has gotten me close, but I still cannot get it right.

EDIT

This sort of works, but I do not know why.

```
note {
  $attributes: a b c;
  $pre: '' "Note";
  $space: '' " ";
  &::before { 
    $content: $pre;
    @each $attribute in $attributes {
      $content: $content + $space + " attr(" + $attribute + ")";
    }; 
    content:  #{$content}; 
  }
}
```

It produces

```
note::before {
  content: "" "Note""" " " attr(a)"" " " attr(b)"" " " attr(c);
}
```

which the browser will handle correctly since it ignores the `""`.

But it is a not-understood hack. What is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Interesting string indeed! You could try this way:

```
note {
  $attributes: a b c;
  $pre: 'Note';
  $space:"' '";
  &::before {
    $content:"";
    @each $attribute in $attributes {
      $content: $content + $space + attr($attribute);
    }
    content:$pre #{$content};
  }
}
```